# Why didn't Mother accept the deactivation of the Nostromo autodestruction procedure?

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-1979

Ellen Ripley seems to complete the deactivation of the request either physically or via a voice command, and Mother rejected accomplishing the task. She didn't want to or wasn't able to?

Comment: It’s not made totally clear in the movie but I recall an implication that the window to disable the self destruct closed before Ripley could complete the disabling procedure. That’s why she’s pushing those columns down to try to make them go faster because she knows she might not finish in time.

Comment: As comment: because of the answer of @K-H-W, the things is now centered if Ripley did the right procedure or mother malfunctioned. AFAIK. the levers are a switch overprotected to avoid a detonation by mistake, but when she turned it off, it should deactivate the reactor/meltdown/explosive process

Comment: I am sure I am not the first to ask why there is any period in which the countdown can't be stopped except, and this is pretty lame, you have an intelligent opponent who you want unable to force you to stop the countdown.

Comment: @releseabe Is that so lame? When would you activate a ship's autodestruct sequence? When the ship has been compromised. You wouldn't want pirates to be able to take over and cancel the countdown. Even a security code could be worked around with something like "Put in the code or I'll blow your head off." I'm skeptical that a system would be designed this way in the real world, but I can see the logic behind it.

Comment: @KefSchecter: I guess a period long enough to allow escape with an **unknown** subperiod in which even stopping the explosion could indeed have its uses. Keeping it secret could be key -- a heroic captain could even kill the pirates by pretending he or she could still stop the sequence seconds before the end. The ship's computer blabbing about it would be something I would disable in my design.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

TL&DR version:  Ripley missed the window to disarm it by seconds.

---

If you look at the system when she's arming it, it makes it clear that there's a 5 minute window to deactivate

[image: Image of the Scuttle instructions]
When she approaches the 5 minute cutoff, you can hear Mother counting down; As Todd-Wilcox mentions in the comments, you see her pushing down on the columns to try to make it go faster, since she can see that she's right at the edge of the time... and she doesn't make it.

She finishes what she's doing at one console, and runs over to push the levers back up to finish the abort... and you hear mother say that "The Option to Override detonation procedure has now Expired."  Ripley was still pushing the levers up when mother starts making the statement, which occurs right at the 5 minute mark.
[image: 5 minute mark]
(First, you see it hit 5 minutes, then it switches back to Ripley pushing the lever up.)
[image: Pushing the Levers]
(One is still all the way down, and she's partway pushed the other up, when 5 minutes hits and Mother makes the announcement.)

She finishes the override steps as Mother hits the word "Now" in "The Option to Override detonation procedure has now Expired."

If it's still up, you can watch the whole deactivation process here, where I got the screencaps. She misses it by seconds, but she does miss it.

Why should mother not help anyway? It's been a while since I've seen the movie, and it might be mentioned somewhere else, but I assumed that since her next comment was "Mother? I've turned the cooling unit back on. Mother?!", that the self-destruct was basically allowing the ship reactor to meltdown (although, for some reason the ship would detonate), and 5 minutes was the point-of-no-return; Mother wasn't trying to be unhelpful, it just wasn't possible to abort, at that point.

Comment: I don't know how reliable it is, but the AVP Fandom seems to back this up at [this page](https://avp.fandom.com/wiki/Emergency_destruction_system#Aboard_the_Nostromo) -- "The emergency destruction system aboard the USCSS Nostromo operated on a ten-minute delay, with an initial five-minute fail-safe window during which the process could be aborted. However, after these five minutes had elapsed, the meltdown of the ship's core was irreversible and could not be stopped. When the ten minutes ended, the ship's core would explode with tremendous force, utterly destroying the spacecraft."

Comment: Very valuable answer, It sprunged more questions on my mind. Biut I will take into another questions.

Comment: What's the caution labels say? *No pinching the screen* ?

Comment: @Mazura "BEWARE STATIC DAMAGE"

Answer (score 9):

> Why should mother not help anyway?

The out-of-universe explanation is a countdown adds tension, and they needed to show Ripley being unable to turn off self-destruct. They don't need to explain why, explaining why would be distracting, it's enough that she tries but she can't.

[K-H-W's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/268165/1441) is good, there is a physical point where self-destruct cannot be stopped. While it may be true that there is such a point, having it a exactly 5 minutes is a bit too neat. This isn't Star Trek where they can calculate everything down to the last second. The Alien universe is gritty and messy. Even if 5 minutes was determined at the factory, with the state of repair of Nostromo it's hard to believe anything works to factory spec.

An alternative, or additional, explanation is that the 5 minute mark is a security mechanism: Mother is programmed to not allow any override.

Why would Nostromo, a civilian cargo vessel, have a self-destruct mechanism in the first place? Because there are situations when leaving the ship intact are far, far worse. For example, if your ship is out of control, drifting towards an inhabited planet, and carrying disease or very dangerous cargo, you really want to make sure its reactor blows up before it gets too close; you don't want any panicking crew to stop the process. Or maybe [your ship is being boarded](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P1xdGCvNMEY); you don't want any plucky heroes turning self-destruct off with 1 second remaining after you've left.

The Emergency Destruct System describes it as a "Failsafe Warning" and cancelling the self-destruct as a "Cut-off system" implying self-destruct is an active process which can be stopped.

[image]

If you set self-destruct and let it tick down to T-5 minutes, the people who programmed Mother assumed that everyone is leaving or has already left and that you [absolutely do indeed want to blow up the ship wholeheartedly](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dm1p9mE9RBw). They didn't contemplate you'd be blocked from the escape pods by ["something never recorded once on over three hundred surveyed worlds"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rkBhLjwuq20#t=1m30.5s).

When Ripley tells Mother she's turned the cooling units back on, she doesn't expect Mother to do anything. Mother doesn't have voice commands, you need to go into [a special room full of blinking lights and type on a keyboard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-6mvwOCYJjc). Mother can't hear her, and Ripley knows that. She's just doing what we all do; she's yelling at a computer in frustration.

Comment: And before someone points out that [Starfleet self-destruct mechanisms can be turned off with 2 seconds remaining](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H7qyDXQeJPY), Starfleet knows their captains will set self-destruct just to prove a point.

Comment: This seems like guesswork. Can you offer any evidence to back this up?

Comment: @Valorum There are some implications from the wording of the self-destruct instructions, but this is just as much speculation as the other answer. 5 minutes is just too neat.

Comment: It's a round number, sure, but [life is full of those](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Everest#:~:text=Peak%20XV%20(measured%20in%20feet,more%20than%20a%20rounded%20estimate.))

Comment: @Valorum I would argue that's an exception that proves the rule. Sure, it's 29,000 ft. [Or is it 29,029 ft? Or 29,029.30 or 29,035 or 29,017.16?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Everest#Surveys) Are we measuring the rock height or the snow height? Has it changed in 100 years? Humans like round numbers, nature does not. Even if it were 5 minutes at the factory, after returning from a long cruise with questionable maintenance, its engines still destruct exactly according to the manufacturer's specs down to the second?

Comment: See my answer below. It's five minutes because the film's makers were lazy and used round numbers :-)

Comment: Sorry, this still doesn't make sense to me for a civilian/corporate vessel.  Those "far, far worse" situations you mention would just not in any way be the responsibility of the individual ships, they'd be the responsibility of the military that defends the planet that the ship is endangering who would likely be plenty able to destroy the hazardous vessel.  Also, using a video that shows a military vessel self-destructing when being boarded is simply not logical when applied to a civilian/corporate vessel in the same situation.

Comment: @CitizenRon If that's so, what is the Nostromo's self-destruct system for?

Comment: The shuttle had an 'abort'. Every time it launched it was someone's job to stand by the button that would kill everyone onboard, so that if it was going to hit Tampa it wouldn't all still be in one piece.

Comment: @Mazura: About that. The shuttle would quickly exceed its aerodynamic limits if powered by uncontrolled SRBs so everybody on board is going to die anyway. As the abort mechanism cut the SRBs it doesn't do anything after SRB burnout. Not attempting to return to FL after loss of more than one liquid fuel engine is left the crew.

Answer (score 8):

In the [original screenplay](https://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/alien_shooting.html), the self-destruct doesn't appear to be an intentional self-destruct *system*, it was just Ripley using her knowledge of the ship's engine to cause the power core to explode.

> MOTHER'S VOICE: (o.s.) Attention.  The cooling units for the light-plus engines are not functioning.  Engines will over-load in four minutes, fifty seconds...

When she tried to remediate her actions less than two minutes later, the damage she'd already caused was sufficient to result in the ship becoming a ticking timebomb. Again, note the absence of a strict cut-off time limit.

> **MOTHER'S VOICE:** (o.s.) *Attention.  Engines will overload in three minutes, twenty seconds.*
>
> **INT. ENGINE ROOM - CUBICLE**
> The door crashes open, Ripley comes pounding in.
> The chamber filled with smoke.
> Engines whining dangerously.
> Ripley breaks out in perspiration from the intense heat.
> She runs to the controls.
> Begins throwing the cooling unit switches back into place.
> The sirens continue sounding.
>
> **MOTHER'S VOICE** (o.s.) *Attention.  Engines will overload in three minutes.*
>
> Ripley pushes a button and speaks into it.
>
> **RIPLEY:** *Mother, I've turned all the cooling units back on.*
>
> **MOTHER'S VOICE:** (o.s.) ***Too late for remedial action. The core has begun to melt.** Engines will overload in two minutes, thirty-five seconds.*

The [official novelisation](https://avp.fandom.com/wiki/Alien_(novel)) also strongly agrees. Mother advises her that the process is simply too far gone to rectify.

> Gasping for breath, she leaned against the hot wall as she jabbed a button. 'Mother, I've turned all the cooling units back on full!'
> '**Too late for remedial action. The drive core has begun to melt. Reaction irreversible at this point.** Implosion incipient, followed by uncontainable overload and subsequent detonation. Engines will overload in two minutes, fifty-five seconds.'

It would appear that the film's makers realised that audiences need a more explicit explanation of why the ship is going to blow up and put in place a handy-dandy self-destruct sign to explain what's happening. Having done so, they also then put nice round numbers in place to make it easier for audiences to realise why it wasn't fixable after she'd changed her mind.

Comment: I'm glad they did, that Emergency Destruction System instruction plate is such a nice touch making the Nostromo seem real.

Comment: @Schwern - Plus it improves the tension and explains what's happening to audience members just getting back from the toilet or looking up from shovelling popcorn into their faces.

Comment: I'm not glad.  I'm always bugged by the idea that Sci-Fi ships need a full-fledged self-destruct system.  If it was a military vessel of some tactical importance, I could more reasonably understand it but in a long range civilian/corporate freight hauler pulling an ore refinery, I just don't see it.  The WY corp explicitly places more value on money than human life and allowing just one of those lowly, easily replaceable humans to blow up tens of millions in starship and who know how much in ore and refinery doesn't gibe.  It just doesn't make sense from a financial or insurance standpoint.

Comment: @CitizenRon - That sounds like an excellent question to [ask](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask); "***Why does the Nostromo even have a self-destruct"***

Comment: No loose ends. Yutani can't let it fall into the hands of the competition that doesn't exist. And if you have a standing order to search for ET life and you put nuclear reactors into their orbit, if something goes wrong you need it to not kill the thing you're looking for by rendering the planet uninhabitable. [**Range Safety**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_safety)

Comment: @Mazura - Except that this is basically a space hauler. It would be like installing a self-destruct in a tugboat.

Comment: @Valorum That brings up the question of whether the destruct mechanism is part of the *Nostromo* or is part of the ore refinery that the *Nostromo* is hauling. Since the refinery has four towers and there are four pistons or whatever for the destruct mechanism, and four explosions, I thought the reactors that explode from the destruct mechanism were part of the refinery, not the *Nostromo*.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - asked here; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/268232/why-would-the-nostromo-have-a-self-destruct-mechanism

Comment: @Valorum I’m not seeing that question nor an answer to it at that link.