# Relationship between turning off cooling system and self destruct -- why was the cooling system involved?

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-1979

Ripley first turns off the cooling system and then turns it back on (when she decides she does not want the ship destroyed which I do not understand) and tells Mother this as she appeals to the computer to stop the self-destruct countdown.

If the cooling system being off is needed for self-destruct then her re-enabling the cooling system should stop the destruction; on the other hand, if the self-destruct proceeds even with the cooling system on, then why turn it off in the first place? To save energy?

Comment: It's not filmed on Earth, naturally the film's logic need not be like Earth logic.

Comment: In the real world there is a concern that a nuclear core can reach a temperature where they become so hot that cooling systems can't cool them enough to prevent a meltdown.

Comment: @Valorum: Simple question: If she wanted the ship to self destruct, why was turning off the cooling system necessary?

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/268163/why-didnt-mother-accept-the-deactivation-of-the-nostromo-autodestruction-proced/268181#268181

Comment: Real world fission reactors do not cause a nuclear explosion when they overheat but it’s bad. *Aliens* franchise **fusion** reactors do cause a “thermonuclear explosion” when they overheat. This is seen in both *Aliens* and *Alien*.

Comment: Also Ripley wants to cancel the self destruct because her initial plan is to leave the xenomorph on the Nostromo and escape in the lifeboat. After initiating self destruct she tries to return to the lifeboat but the xenomorph is there - so she can’t get off the Nostromo. She figures she’s got to cancel the self destruct and then come up with another plan. But she can’t cancel the self destruct so she has to figure out how to get on the lifeboat and “luckily” the xenomorph is no longer blocking access to the lifeboat so she escapes the Nostromo before it destructs.

Answer (score 5):

> The emergency destruction system aboard the USCSS Nostromo operated on a ten-minute delay, with an initial five-minute fail-safe window during which the process could be aborted. However, after these five minutes had elapsed, the meltdown of the ship's core was irreversible and could not be stopped.

https://avp.fandom.com/wiki/Emergency_destruction_system

Reading that, it takes 5 minutes for the coolant not operating to let the powerplant go into meltdown, and after 5 minutes, this is irreversible.

That is why the timer to cancel the self destruct is also 5 minutes - beyond that there is no stopping of what destruction comes with a powerplant meltdown.

....

In addition to what Valorum said (in the comments), it is generally accepted that anything generating power, generates heat, and needs cooling to not meltdown or explode. Space in itself can be very hot, or very cold, *(Note the International Space Station has a very active cooling and heat dissipation system running)* but in this context its probably that without cooling systems on, the ship is a very inhospitable place to work

Also, in the script, they make references to the life support requiring coolant to operate:

(transcript) Ripley:

```
We're gonna need coolant for
the air support system.

You two go down, get all
the coolant you can carry.
```

In light of the answer that Valorum linked to in the comments, it is more likely that the coolant was for power plant, and at 5 minutes to go, with coolant switched off, meltdown was irreversible.

For reference, some spaceships operated with explosive self-destruct devices at the time the movie was in production. This was separate to the FTS, range safety self destruct for launchers, which still operates today (Russians just turn off the engines for self-destruct during launch-phase, but the Soyuz operating from Kourou have FTS added).

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/268181/140676

> *Ripley first turns off the cooling system and then turns it back on (when she decides she does not want the ship destroyed which I do not understand)*

Ripley decides she does not want the ship destroyed because originally she was going to leave in the escape craft, leaving the alien to get blown up along with the ship - but after setting the self-destruct and heading towards the escape craft, she found her route blocked by the alien, so she needed more time (than the self-destruct was going to give her) in order make a *new* plan to get to the escape craft.

Comment: Maybe she needed to turn off the cooling system so she had enough for the shuttle. I think this must be it.

Comment: @releseabe - That's not it. You've completely misunderstood

Answer (score 2):

### The Nostramo is powered by a nuclear reactor

This is what happens when the cooling system of a nuclear reactor fails:

[image: Chernobyl nuclear disaster]

It is important to understand, that what you see here is not the aftermath of a *nuclear* explosion (there wouldn’t be anything to see after that) but the result of a [*steam* explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steam_explosion).

The basic process in nuclear power is there is a core undergoing a nuclear reaction (fission or fusion) which generates a huge amount of heat. That heat is transferred to a coolant (usually water) which becomes a superheated vapour and is taken somewhere else and used to do work, typically driving a turbine to generate electricity. The coolant then condenses and gets sent back to the reactor to do it again.

If you stop the coolant circulating, then you make more and more steam which, at some point, rips the pipes apart in a massive explosion. It doesn’t actually matter what the primary energy source was - coal-fired steam locomotives, gas-fired power stations can all fail in this way.

### The self-destruct stops the coolant flowing

So, it starts to heat up. It will take 10 minutes of this before something, somewhere, ruptures with a big bang. Given that they can state the precise time, I guess there’s was a deliberate weak point with a known fail pressure built into the coolant system. Without that, when and where the failure will occur would be just a guess.

However, once the system has been off for 5 minutes, even if it is restarted, there is too much heat built up to be dissipated and the explosion is inevitable. Or, perhaps, the coolant is now so hot that it actually prevents the system from being restarted.

Comment: This answer doesn’t make sense in relation to the film. Specifically, why in the film are there four explosions instead of one? And why are all four explosions just massively huge? They’re nothing like the kind of explosion that can occur at a real world fission reactor.

Comment: @ToddWilcox maybe there are 4 reactors, or 4 cooling systems and steam explosions can be “massively huge”.